# Solving a radical equation for real roots

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials, roots, radicals

I'm attempting to solve the derivative of my function $f(x)$ for real roots.
$$
\\ \begin{align*}
\\ f(x) &= 3x^2 + 3\arcsin{x}
\\ f^{\prime}(x) &= 6x + \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\\ 
\\ 0 &= 6x + \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\\
\\ 0 &= 6x \sqrt{1-x^2} + 3
\\ 0 &= \sqrt{36x^2 - 36x^4} + 3
\\ -3 &= \sqrt{36x^2-36x^4}
\\ (-3)^2 &= (\sqrt{36x^2-36x^4})^2
\\ 0 &= -36x^4 + 36x^2 - 9
\\ \frac{0}{9} &= \frac{9(-4x^4 + 4x^2 - 1)}{9}
\\ 0 &= -4x^4 + 4x^2 - 1
\\ \end{align*}
$$

I've considered the rational root theorem at this point, through which I find possible roots to be $x = \{ \pm1, \pm\frac{1}{2}, \pm\frac{1}{4} \}$.

Clearly I've made an error, as the actual root is $x = -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: The last line where you get to $0=-4x^4+4x^2-1$ appears to be the problem.  Perhaps you could expound on how you got there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0(-1)=(-4x^4+4x^2-1)(-1) \\ 
0=4x^4-4x^2+1 \\
 0=(2x^2-1)^2$

Comment: I added one more step. That first line. I multiplied what you had on both sides by -1. @Alex

Answer (score 1):

Your work is correct, $1/\sqrt 2$ is indeed a root of $-4x^4+4x^2-1$. The rational root test just tells you that the only possible *rational* roots of your polynomial are $\pm 1$, $\pm 1/2$ and $\pm 1/4$, it doesn't tell you anything about possible irrational roots, so there's no contradiction. For example, the rational root test also tells you that the only possible rational roots of $x^2-2$ are $\pm 1$ and $\pm 2$, but that doesn't contradict the fact that the actual roots are $\pm\sqrt 2$.

You can easily solve $-4x^4+4x^2-1=0$ by writing it as $-4(x^2)^2+4x^2-1=0$, solving for $x^2$ and then taking a square root.

Comment: Oh, silly me. I hadn't considered that point. So:

$$
\\ \begin{align*}
\\ 0 &= -4x^4 + 4x^2 - 1
\\ 0 &= -4x^2(x^2 - 1) - 1
\\ 0 &= -4x^2(x+1)(x-1) - 1
\\ 1 &= -4x^2(x+1)(x-1)
\\ \dfrac{-1}{4(x+1)(x-1)} &= x^2
\\ \pm\sqrt{\dfrac{-1}{4(x+1)(x-1)}} &= x
\\ \end{align*}
$$

Comment: This result I've come to doesn't seem too useful, I think I need to take a different approach.

Comment: You could do the quadratic formula. OR! Just use what I did above. $a^2-2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2$

Comment: @randomgirl This is a quartic, though, not a quadratic.

Comment: Let $u=x^2$ Solve $-4u^2+4u-1=0$

Comment: @randomgirl I see.

Answer (score 0):

When you find yourself in such a situation, a good trick is to insert the root (any number will work but the root will often make the calculations easy) at each step and see when the value change.

Personally I think you are doing to much at once in the last step.

Comment: From steps:
$$
\\ \begin{align*}
\\ 0 &= 6x \sqrt{1-x^2} + 3 \text{ where } x = -1/sqrt{2}
\\ 0 &= \sqrt{36x^2 - 36x^4} + 3 \text{ where } x = -1/sqrt{2}
\\ \end{align*}
$$

The transformation of equality becomes untrue, but I don't see how, exactly. Am I going about solving this root wrong to begin with, this is rather involved for finding a root?

If it were simply a polynomial I could just use the rational root theorem, is there perhaps some equivalent for this equation?